# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, android, casting

I have done with code in Android:

```
List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    LinkedTreeMap<String, String> item = (LinkedTreeMap) items.get(i);

    // THIS LINE THROW EXCEPTION
    double d = Double.parseDouble(item.get("id").toString());

    locations.put(Integer.parseInt(item.get("id")), item.get("name"));
    spinnerArray.add(item.get("name"));
}
```

I get the error when I define the "d" variable.
The strange thing is if I run the same line in the debug I get the double value I need.

**UPDATE ANSWER**

On the debug window I have:

```
items.get(i) = {LinkedTreeMap@5317} size = 5
0 = {LinkedTreeMap$Node@5378} "id" -> "1.0"
    key = "id"
    value = {Double@5384} "1.0"
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, item.get("id") will return you a String so why use .toString() ?

Comment: You don't need `toString()`. Also, is it a double or an integer? You're parsing the ID twice

Comment: To try everything :( I already tried without .ToString() and I get the error, so I tried with .ToString()

Comment: Please add the stacktrace to the question

Comment: The only casting is happening at (LinkedTreeMap) items.get(i) . What does items contain?

Comment: Try to print the value before pars.....

Comment: Add a [mcve].... `items` is the source of the problem

Comment: post your locations map init statement !!

Comment: You declare `item` as LinkedTreeMap<String, String> but you missuse it  as a "custom Object type" so that different keys have different value types. Therefore `item` must be declared as `LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that LinkedTreeMap `items` is of type [String, Object] and not [String, String].

So your code should look like:

```
LinkedTreeMap<String, Object> item = (LinkedTreeMap) items.get(i);
```

Thanks to Timothy Truckle.

Comment: Close, but the OP missuses the map as a "custom Object type" so that different keys have different value types. Therefore `item` must be `LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>`

Answer (score 1):

The long term solution to your problem is to define a *custom class* to be used as *Data Transfer Object* (DTO) where you cann access an items properties in a typesafe way:

```
class Item {
   private double id;
   private String name;
   public void setId(double id){this.id=id;}
   public double getId(){ return id;}
   public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
   public String getName(){return name;}
}
```

usage:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    Item item = (LinkedTreeMap) items.get(i);

    // THIS LINE THROW EXCEPTION
    double d = item.getId();

    locations.put((int)item.getId(), item.getName());
```